# What does "supports compatible features on older versions" mean?

Tags: android-support-library, androidx

[Android official document says "Allows access to new APIs on older API versions of the platform (many using Material Design)."][1]

For example, [android:backgroundTint][2] is available to API level 21, but
[AppCompatTextView][3] makes it available for lower API levels. That is exactly what the official document says:

> A TextView which supports compatible features on older versions of the
> platform, including:  Allows setting of the background tint using
> backgroundTint and backgroundTintMode

However, I get the following warning when I use [AppCompatTextView][3]:

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Could anyone shed some light on exact meaning of "supports compatible features on older versions"?
[1]: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat
[2]: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:backgroundTint
[3]: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatTextView
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYTaR.png